# Fixed points of an endomorphism of a ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, fixed-point-theorems

Let $R$ be a commutative $k$-algebra, where $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.
Let $f$ be a $k$-algebra endomorphism of $R$. ($f$ is not assumed to be either injective nor surjective).

> Are there additional conditions (on $R$ or on $f$) that guarantee that $f$ has a fixed point $r \in R-k$? Namely, $r \in R-k$ such that $f(r)=r$.
>
> I do not mind to restrict my question to the special case $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $f$ having an invertible Jacobian. (Below I am trying to solve the case $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $f$ having an invertible Jacobian).

**Remarks:** **(1)** By definition, $f(\lambda)=\lambda$ for every $\lambda \in k$, hence I required that $r \in R-k$.

**(2)** 'fixed point theorems' tag shows that there are several nice theorems concerning fixed points of functions, but additional structures on $R$ are needed.

**(3)** Perhaps [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590367/algebraic-fixed-point-theorem?rq=1) is relevant. (Notice that here the set of fixed points of $f$ is a $k$-subalgebra of $R$, but it may happen that it equals $k$; the point is to find a fixed point outside $k$).

**(4)** See also [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/118162?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), in which the following is proved: If $f:k[x,y] \to k[x,y]$ has an invertible Jacobian and is not an automorphism, then $\cap f^i(k[x,y])=k$. Then it follows that if $f$ has a fixed point $r \in k[x,y]-k$, then 
$r \in \cap f^i(k[x,y])$, so $\cap f^i(k[x,y]) \neq k$, hence $f$ is an automorphism of $k[x,y]$.

**The special case $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$:** Consider $R=k[x]$ and $f: x \mapsto a_mx^m+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$, $a_i \in k$. If $f$ has an invertible Jacobian, namely, $ma_mx^{m-1}+\cdots+a_1= (a_mx^m+\cdots+a_1x+a_0)' \in k^{\times}$, then $a_2=\ldots=a_m=0$, $a_1 \in k^{\times}$, $a_0 \in k$, so  $f: x \mapsto a_1x+a_0$; for convenience, write $f: x \mapsto ux+v$.

If $r=\sum_{j=0}^{n} b_jx^j$ is a fixed point of $f$, then
$\sum_{j=0}^{n} b_j(u^jx^j+\cdots+v^j)= \sum b_j(ux+v)^j= \sum b_jf(x)^j=f(\sum b_jx^j)=f(r)=r=\sum_{j=0}^{n} b_jx^j$

Therefore, $b_nu^n=b_n$, so $b_n(u^n-1)=0$, hence $u^n=1$. (Also, if $v \neq 0$, then $\sum_{j=0}^{n}b_j=b_0$, so $\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_j=0$).

We obtained that $f$, having an invertible Jacobian, has a fixed point $r \in R-k$ if $f: x \mapsto ux+v$ with $u^n=1$ for some $n$ (and other conditions).

For example, $k=\mathbb{C}$, $f: x \mapsto -x$, here $n=2$, so we take $r$ of degree $2$: $r=x^2$:
$f(r)=f(x^2)=f(x)^2=(-x)^2=x^2=r$.

Another example: $k=\mathbb{C}$, $f: x \mapsto ix$, here $n=4$, so we take $r$ of degree $4$: $r=x^4$:
$f(r)=f(x^4)=f(x)^4=(ix)^4=(i^4)x^4=x^4=r$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This question is far too broad. Obviously there are conditions that guarantee that $f$ has a fixed point in $R \setminus k$ (assuming $R \neq k$). E.g., you could require $f$ to be the identity function. What kind of conditions are you looking for?

Comment: ok, I agree with your comment. I think that I am looking for conditions such as: $R$ being a UFD/Noetherian/of finite Krull dimension etc. Actually, even for a specific $R$ like $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, I am not sure what happens for a general $f$. (It seems that there is an answer to the case $\mathbb{C}[x]$).

Comment: I will immediately elaborate on these two special cases in my question.

Comment: It sounds from your comment that you are interested in conditions on $R$ that guarantee that every endomorphism $f$ has a fixed point in $R \setminus k$. If so, then please reword your question to say that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was hoping to get an answer (though I thought that the chances are quite low), for general $R$ and $f$. However, I will be happy to get an answer for $R=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_N]$ and $f$ having an invertible Jacobian. I am trying to solve the case $N=1$ myself, and it would be nice to know the answer for the case $N=2$ ($N \geq 3$ seems more complicated). Actually, the case $N=2$ should be very very difficult.

Comment: in your "special case", why is $f$ with the form you described even an algebra morphism?

Comment: Thanks. We define $f$ so that it becomes a $k$-algebra endomorphism, namely, we define: $f(x^i)=f(x)^i$, $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$.

Comment: then $f$ shouldn't be of the form $f(x)=a_0+\dots a_mx^m$ for all $x\in R$ and some $a_i$ in $k$ because $f$ just doesn't satisfy these properties.

Comment: "...for all $x \in R$": We are talking about different things; in my special case $R=k[x]$, so every element of $R$ is a polynomial in one variable $x$. For example, for $f(x)=x^2$, we just have, for example, $f(x^3+5x)=f(x)^3+5f(x)=(x^2)^3+5x^2=x^6+5x^2$.

Comment: Perhaps you had in mind an arbitrary (commutative) $k$-algebra $R$, not necessarily $R=k[x]$, and then you thought that I define $f(w)=a_0+\ldots+a_mw^m$, for every $w \in R$, which indeed is usually not a $k$-algebra endomorphism of rings. For example, if $f(w)=w^2$, then $f(w_1+w_2)=(w_1+w_2)^2 \neq w_1^2+w_2^2=f(w_1)+f(w_2)$.